# 3-qubit phase shift gate/circuit implementation without any Ancilla qubits

Tags: quantum-gate, circuit-construction, unitarity, quantum-phase-estimation, quantum-circuit

[image]

Hi, I need help me with figuring out the 3-qubit phase shift circuit without any ancillas similar to the 2-qubit circuit shown in below attached picture....... Please do let me know! Thanks in advance! Also, I've written down the matrix/operator equivalent to 3-qubit phase-shift circuit in the picture itself... Restrictions would be to not use any Ancilla's and it would be better if we can implement using only CNOT & single qubit gates.

Comment: Ignore the above-written 3x3 Matrix... it's supposed to be an 8x8 matrix for a 3-qubit system circuit!! So, think of the solution circuit as an 8x8 matrix which is an extension of the above-drawn 3x3 matrix......

Comment: Do you know about the standard construction for a controlled-controlled-$U$ gate? See, for example, Fig 4.8 in Nielsen & Chuang.